# how to give a check whether the client machine has .net 6 installed or not if install then is that greater then .net runtime 6.0.0 in wix bootstarper

Tags: wix, .net-6.0, wix3.11, .net-runtime

Here I have created that condition

```
<bal:Condition
Message="This setup requires Microsoft .NET 6.0 or above.">
        <![CDATA[NET6VERSION >= 6.0.0]]>
    </bal:Condition>
```

then I have declare the variable in the wix.

```
<Variable Name="NET6VERSION" bal:Overridable="yes" Type="numeric" Value="0" />
```

then the registry search for the .net 6 .

```
<util:RegistrySearch
        Id="DotNet6RegistrySearch"
        Root="HKLM"
        Key="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64\sharedfx\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App"
        Value="Version"
        Variable="NET6VERSION"
        Result="value"  />
```

so I want to give a check that if the client machine installed .net is greater the .net v6.0.0 then the setup should allow to insatll.

please help me to find the solution.